# Eclipse Not Starting, no help from google answers

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

Ive been frustrated with problem since a day. I can't get eclipse to work.

I did a fresh install of win 10 x64 2 days ago.

I have installed java jdk 1.7 x64 bit, and set the JAVA_HOME & PATH variables Properly(I checked by using java,javac,java -version,javac -version and echo %JAVA_HOME%, on default CMD window from run).

Surprisingly,Android Studio is running perfectly.

But eclipse wont.(error : eclipse could not start Java virtual machine)

I uninstalled, reinstalled... nothing changes. I set the java path in eclipse.ini. then finally the eclipse splash screen appeared for the 1st time.(pointing to javaw.exe gave error that eclipse could not start Java virtual machine)

But then it would crash giving the error msg to check the log.

When i checked the log the last few lines state (the log is around 1000 lines)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.nativePackageExtractor, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core.SetupArchiver, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

I've searched google up and down but i cant seem to find a solution!

I'm pasting the eclipse.ini and configuration\config.ini files for you to review.

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

config.ini

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Fri Oct 07 13:01:29 EDT 2016
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20    160504-1450.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpl    econfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.0.v201605131737.jar
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
```

I am ripping my hair out trying to find a solution to this.

Note: Everything is a fresh install. Java,Eclipse, Android Studio, Windows. System is 64 bit and so are all the installation files.

Please Help

Comment: Whats is eclipse version ? and did you look here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493223

Comment: Hi Bhavil, I found some differences in Eclipse.ini at line 4, as you are using 64 bit version, lets try by removing X86_. new file should contain the X64_

Comment: This line here `-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin` specifies the JVM that will be used to start eclipse. Does that path exist; is it the 64 bit version?

Comment: @VijayKarchi `x86_64` is correct for 64 bit Eclipse.

Comment: @GhostCat : As I said, pointing to javaw.exe/java.exe gave error could not start JVM, or java started but exited with error code 1!. pointing it ti jvm.dll made it work but with the error stated in the main question

Comment: What I mean is: that PATH used in the eclipse.ini for -vm ... you are 100% sure that the path there is valid?! Your Java home setup does **not** matter when the .ini file contains a -vm setting!

Comment: @Azodious : The Eclipse Version Is neon. Extracted from (eclipse-jee-neon-1a-win32-x86_64.zip).

also the ".eclipsePoduct" files states version to be 4.6.1

Comment: @GhostCat: yes, I'm very sure that my jdk is installed to that location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, This is rather embarrassing... The problem was Java.. eclipse neon requires Java 8. Installed that and everything was up and running.

Thank you for the help everyone. :)